# How to configure Action<T> with dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, delegates

I am trying to learn how `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` are working, for this I've created a base class which requires an `Action<AppConfiguration>` in it's constructor among other dependencies:

```
public abstract class GenericOracleTDRRepository<T> : IGenericTDRRepository<T>
{
        protected GenericOracleTDRRepository(ILogger<GenericOracleTDRRepository<T>> logger,
                                             Action<AppConfiguration> configuration,
                                             IUpdateSqlStringGenerator<T> generator)
        {
            if (configuration is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            }

            Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            configuration(AppSettings);
            _generator = generator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(generator));
        }

      public AppConfiguration AppSettings { get; private set; } = new AppConfiguration();
}



public class RmesgOracleReposityory : GenericOracleTDRRepository<RMesg>, IGenericTDRRepository<RMesg>
{
    public RmesgOracleReposityory(ILogger<RmesgOracleReposityory> logger,
                                  Action<AppConfiguration> appSettings,
                                  IUpdateSqlStringGenerator<RMesg> generator) : base(logger, appSettings, generator)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public new ILogger<RmesgOracleReposityory> Logger { get; }
}
```

I am configuring it in my DI container:

```
services.AddScoped<IGenericTDRRepository<RMesg>, RmesgOracleReposityory>();
services.AddTransient<IUpdateSqlStringGenerator<RMesg>, UpdateSqlStringGenerator<RMesg>>();
```

I am not sure where and how should I pass a valid `Action<AppConfiguration>` for this object?

Comment: You need to define the `Action<AppConfiguration>` to use somewhere. Where is it coming from? If you always use the same action, it makes no sense to inject it. Then you might as well define a method directly in the class.

Comment: Can I define it in the class `RmesgOracleReposityory ` that is inheriting from `GenericOracleTDRRepository<T>`?

Comment: Well, yes, You can then pass it to the base class' constructor. But why do you need an action injected into the base class in the first place?

Comment: I have a project with a console app and a WPF app. In the console app I am reading values from appsettings.json and map it to AppSettings object, but for WPF app I want to create a new AppSettings object with the values entered by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `Action<AppConfiguration>` to use somewhere.

If you for example define it in the `Startup` class, you could use the overload of `AddScoped` that accepts an `IServiceProvider` to resolve the other dependencies and inject it like this:

```
void TheAction(AppConfiguration appConfiguration) { }

services.AddScoped<IGenericTDRRepository<RMesg>, RmesgOracleReposityory>(serviceProvider =>
{
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RmesgOracleReposityory>>();
    var generator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUpdateSqlStringGenerator<RMesg>>();
    return new RmesgOracleReposityory(logger, TheAction, generator);
});
```

You might also define it in the `RmesgOracleReposityory` class and pass it to the base class' constructor:

```
public class RmesgOracleReposityory : GenericOracleTDRRepository<RMesg>, IGenericTDRRepository<RMesg>
{
    public RmesgOracleReposityory(ILogger<RmesgOracleReposityory> logger,
                                  IUpdateSqlStringGenerator<RMesg> generator) 
        : base(logger, TheAction, generator)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    private void TheAction(AppConfiguration appConfiguration) { }

    public new ILogger<RmesgOracleReposityory> Logger { get; }
}
```

An `Action<T>` just encapsulates a `void` method that takes a single parameter of type `T`.